# pjsip Assertion failed: mod_tsx_layer.endpt==((void *)0)

Tags: ios, pjsip

I'm using the following code to initialize pjsua.

```
     status = pjsua_create();
     if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
     error_exit("Error in pjsua_create()", status);

     // Init pjsua
     {
     // Init the config structure
     pjsua_config cfg;
     pjsua_config_default (&cfg);


     cfg.cb.on_incoming_call = &on_incoming_call;
     cfg.cb.on_call_media_state = &on_call_media_state;
     cfg.cb.on_call_state = &on_call_state;
     cfg.cb.on_reg_state2 = &on_reg_state2;
     cfg.cb.on_call_tsx_state = &on_call_tsx_state;


     // Init the logging config structure
     pjsua_logging_config log_cfg;
     pjsua_logging_config_default(&log_cfg);
     log_cfg.console_level = 4;

     // Init the pjsua
     status = pjsua_init(&cfg, &log_cfg, NULL);
     if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
     error_exit("Error in pjsua_init()", status);
     }

     // Add UDP transport.
     {
        // Init transport config structure
         pjsua_transport_config cfg; //For the one on public
         pjsua_transport_config_default(&cfg);
         cfg.port = SIP_PORT;

         // Add UDP transport.
         status = pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP, &cfg, NULL);
         if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error creating transport", status);
     }

     // Add TCP transport.
     {
     // Init transport config structure
     pjsua_transport_config cfg;
     pjsua_transport_config_default(&cfg);
     cfg.port = SIP_PORT;
     //cfg.port=sipPORT;



     // Add TCP transport.
     status = pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_TCP, &cfg, NULL);
     if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error creating transport", status);
     }



     // Initialization is done, now start pjsua
     status = pjsua_start();

     if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error starting pjsua", status);
     // Register the account on local sip server
     {
     pjsua_acc_config cfg;

     pjsua_acc_config_default(&cfg);

     // Account ID
     char sipId[MAX_SIP_ID_LENGTH];
     sprintf(sipId, "sip:%s@%s", sipUser, sipDomain);
     cfg.id = pj_str(sipId);

     // Reg URI
     char regUri[MAX_SIP_REG_URI_LENGTH];
     //sprintf(regUri, "sip:%s", sipDomain);
     sprintf(regUri, "sip:%s", sipDomain);

     cfg.reg_uri = pj_str(regUri);

     NSLog(@"regUri %s",regUri);

     // Account cred info
     cfg.cred_count = 1;
     cfg.cred_info[0].scheme = pj_str("digest");

     cfg.cred_info[0].realm = pj_str("*"); 

     //cfg.cred_info[0].realm = pj_str(sipDomain);
     cfg.cred_info[0].username = pj_str(sipUser);
     cfg.cred_info[0].data_type = PJSIP_CRED_DATA_PLAIN_PASSWD;
     cfg.cred_info[0].data = pj_str(password);


     status = pjsua_acc_add(&cfg, PJ_TRUE, &_acc_id);
     if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error adding account", status);

     }


    pj_pool_t *pool = NULL;
    unsigned i;

    /* Must init PJLIB first: */
    status = pj_init();
    PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(status == PJ_SUCCESS, 1);

    pj_log_set_level(5);

    /* Then init PJLIB-UTIL: */
    status = pjlib_util_init();
    PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(status == PJ_SUCCESS, 1);



    /* Must create a pool factory before we can allocate any memory. */
    pj_caching_pool_init(&cp, &pj_pool_factory_default_policy, 0);


    /* Create global endpoint: */
    {
        const pj_str_t *hostname;
        const char *endpt_name;

        /* Endpoint MUST be assigned a globally unique name.
         * The name will be used as the hostname in Warning header.
         */

        /* For this implementation, we'll use hostname for simplicity */
        hostname = pj_gethostname();
        endpt_name = hostname->ptr;

        /* Create the endpoint: */

        status = pjsip_endpt_create(&cp.factory, endpt_name,
                                    &g_endpt);

        PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(status == PJ_SUCCESS, 1);
    }

    /*
     * Add UDP transport, with hard-coded port
     * Alternatively, application can use pjsip_udp_transport_attach() to
     * start UDP transport, if it already has an UDP socket (e.g. after it
     * resolves the address with STUN).
     */

    {
        pj_sockaddr addr;

        pj_sock_t sock;
        pjsip_transport *p_trans;
        pjsip_host_port *host_port;
        host_port->host=pj_str("10.10.10.10");
        host_port->port=5060;


        status=pj_sock_socket(AF,pj_SOCK_DGRAM(),PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP,&sock);

        if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) 
         {
            app_perror(THIS_FILE, "Unable to init pj sock", status);
            return 1;
        }


        if (AF == pj_AF_INET())
        {

            status = pjsip_udp_transport_attach(g_endpt,sock,host_port,1,&p_trans);
        }


        else if (AF == pj_AF_INET6()) {
            status = pjsip_udp_transport_start6(g_endpt, &addr.ipv6, NULL,
                                                1, NULL);
        }
        else
        {
            status = PJ_EAFNOTSUP;
        }

        if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) {
            app_perror(THIS_FILE, "Unable to start UDP transport", status);
            return 1;
        }




    }


    /*
     * Init transaction layer.
     * This will create/initialize transaction hash tables etc.
     */

    //printf("Endpoint: %s\n", pjsip_endpt_name(g_endpt)->ptr);

    status = pjsip_tsx_layer_init_module(g_endpt);
    PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(status == PJ_SUCCESS, 1);


    /*
     * Initialize UA layer module.
     * This will create/initialize dialog hash tables etc.
     */

    status = pjsip_ua_init_module( g_endpt, NULL );
    PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(status == PJ_SUCCESS, 1);
```

But I'm facing a serious problem. The program execution stops at this error.

```
 Assertion failed: mod_tsx_layer.endpt==((void *)0),
    file pjsip\src\pjsip\sip_transaction.c, line 436
```

Though I'm initializing and attaching the UDP transaction layer two times differently. I didn't create transport layer second time. what is the problem with this code? You can also check the problem posted in [this](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/ticket/1470) link.

Answer (score 0):

remove this section :

```
// Init the logging config structure
pjsua_logging_config log_cfg;
pjsua_logging_config_default(&log_cfg);
og_cfg.console_level = 4;
```

and check it

Comment: Is this code is to handle connection when network changes occur in SIP? Because right now I have to crreate new connection every time whenever network changes occue in SIP in ios.

Answer (score 0):

Please review this  code,  may be you will get  your solutions.

```
pj_status_t sip_startup(app_config_t *app_config)
{
  pj_status_t status;
  long val;
  char tmp[80];
  pjsua_transport_id transport_id = -1;

  const char *srv;

  const char *ip_addr;

  NSArray * array;
  NSString *dns;

  AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[AppDelegate sharedApplication];

  /* Create pjsua first! */
  status = pjsua_create();
  if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
    return status;

  /* Create pool for application */
  app_config->pool = pjsua_pool_create("pjsua", 1000, 1000);

  /* Initialize default config */
  pjsua_config_default(&(app_config->cfg));
  pj_ansi_snprintf(tmp, 80, "Siphon PjSip v%s/%s", pj_get_version(), PJ_OS_NAME);
  pj_strdup2_with_null(app_config->pool, &(app_config->cfg.user_agent), tmp);

  pjsua_logging_config_default(&(app_config->log_cfg));

  val = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey: 
         @"logLevel"];
#ifdef RELEASE_VERSION
  app_config->log_cfg.msg_logging = PJ_FALSE;
  app_config->log_cfg.console_level = 0;
  app_config->log_cfg.level = 0;
#else  
  app_config->log_cfg.msg_logging = (val!=0 ? PJ_TRUE : PJ_FALSE);
  app_config->log_cfg.console_level = val;
  app_config->log_cfg.level = val;
  if (val != 0)
  {
#if defined(CYDIA) && (CYDIA == 1)
    NSArray *filePaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Siphon", [filePaths objectAtIndex:0]];
#else
    NSArray *filePaths =    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                                               NSUserDomainMask,
                                                               YES); 
        NSString *path = [filePaths objectAtIndex: 0];
#endif
    //NSString *path = NSTemporaryDirectory();
    path = [path stringByAppendingString: @"/log.txt"];

    app_config->log_cfg.log_filename = pj_strdup3(app_config->pool, 
                                                  [path UTF8String]);
  }
#endif

  pjsua_media_config_default(&(app_config->media_cfg));

  // TODO select clock rate with enabled codec (8000 if nb codec only, or 16000 and more if wb codec)
  //app_config->media_cfg.clock_rate = 8000;
  //app_config->media_cfg.snd_clock_rate = 8000;
  app_config->media_cfg.clock_rate = 16000;
  app_config->media_cfg.snd_clock_rate = 16000;
  //app_config->media_cfg.ec_options = 0;//0=default,1=speex, 2=suppressor

  if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"enableEC"])
    app_config->media_cfg.ec_tail_len = 0;

  // Enable/Disable VAD/silence detector
  app_config->media_cfg.no_vad = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
                                  boolForKey:@"disableVad"];

  app_config->media_cfg.snd_auto_close_time = 0;
  //app_config->media_cfg.quality = 2;
  //app_config->media_cfg.channel_count = 2;

  app_config->media_cfg.enable_ice = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
                                      boolForKey:@"enableICE"];

  pjsua_transport_config_default(&(app_config->udp_cfg));
  val = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey: @"localPort"];
  if (val < 0 || val > 65535)
  {
    PJ_LOG(1,(THIS_FILE, 
      "Error: local-port argument value (expecting 0-65535"));
    [app displayParameterError:
     @"Invalid value for Local Port (expecting 1-65535)."];

    status = PJ_EINVAL;
    goto error;
  }
  app_config->udp_cfg.port = val;

  pjsua_transport_config_default(&(app_config->rtp_cfg));
  app_config->rtp_cfg.port = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
    integerForKey: @"rtpPort"];  
  if (app_config->rtp_cfg.port == 0) 
  {
    enum { START_PORT=4000 };
    unsigned range;

    range = (65535-START_PORT-PJSUA_MAX_CALLS*2);
    app_config->rtp_cfg.port = START_PORT + 
            ((pj_rand() % range) & 0xFFFE);
  }

  if (app_config->rtp_cfg.port < 1 || app_config->rtp_cfg.port > 65535) 
  {
    PJ_LOG(1,(THIS_FILE,
        "Error: rtp-port argument value (expecting 1-65535)"));
    [app displayParameterError:
     @"Invalid value for RTP port (expecting 1-65535)."];
    status = PJ_EINVAL;
    goto error;
  }

#if 1 // TEST pour le vpn
  ip_addr = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey: 
              @"boundAddr"] UTF8String];
  if (ip_addr && strlen(ip_addr))
  {
    pj_strdup2_with_null(app_config->pool, 
                         &(app_config->udp_cfg.bound_addr), 
                         ip_addr);
    pj_strdup2_with_null(app_config->pool, 
                         &(app_config->rtp_cfg.bound_addr), 
                         ip_addr);
  }

  ip_addr = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey: 
              @"publicAddr"] UTF8String];
  if (ip_addr && strlen(ip_addr))
  {
    pj_strdup2_with_null(app_config->pool, 
                         &(app_config->udp_cfg.public_addr), 
                         ip_addr);
    pj_strdup2_with_null(app_config->pool, 
                         &(app_config->rtp_cfg.public_addr), 
                         ip_addr);
  }
#endif

  /* Initialize application callbacks */
  app_config->cfg.cb.on_call_state = &on_call_state;
  app_config->cfg.cb.on_call_media_state = &on_call_media_state;
  app_config->cfg.cb.on_incoming_call = &on_incoming_call;
  app_config->cfg.cb.on_reg_state = &on_reg_state;
#if defined(MWI) && MWI==1
  app_config->cfg.cb.on_mwi_info = &on_mwi_info;
  app_config->cfg.enable_unsolicited_mwi = PJ_TRUE;
#endif

  srv = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey: 
              @"stunServer"] UTF8String];
  if (srv && strlen(srv))
  {
    if (app_config->cfg.stun_srv_cnt==PJ_ARRAY_SIZE(app_config->cfg.stun_srv)) 
    {
      PJ_LOG(1,(THIS_FILE, "Error: too many STUN servers"));
      return PJ_ETOOMANY;
    }
    pj_strdup2_with_null(app_config->pool, 
                         &(app_config->cfg.stun_srv[app_config->cfg.stun_srv_cnt++]), 
                         srv);
  }

 // app_config->cfg.outbound_proxy[0] = pj_str(outbound_proxy);
 // app_config->cfg.outbound_proxy_cnt = 1;

  dns = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey: @"dnsServer"];
  array = [dns componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
  NSEnumerator *enumerator = [array objectEnumerator];
  NSString *anObject;
  while (anObject = [enumerator nextObject])
  {
    NSMutableString *mutableStr = [anObject mutableCopy];
    CFStringTrimWhitespace((CFMutableStringRef)mutableStr);
    srv = [mutableStr UTF8String];
    if (srv && strlen(srv))
    {
      if (app_config->cfg.nameserver_count==PJ_ARRAY_SIZE(app_config->cfg.nameserver)) 
      {
        PJ_LOG(1,(THIS_FILE, "Error: too many DNS servers"));
        [mutableStr release];
        break;
      }
      pj_strdup2_with_null(app_config->pool, 
                           &(app_config->cfg.nameserver[app_config->cfg.nameserver_count++]), 
                           srv);
    }
      [mutableStr release];
  }
  //[enumerator release];
  //[array release];

  /* Initialize pjsua */
  status = pjsua_init(&app_config->cfg, &app_config->log_cfg, 
    &app_config->media_cfg);
  if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
    goto error;

  /* Initialize Ring and Ringback */
  sip_ring_init(app_config);

  /* Add UDP transport. */
  status = pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP,
          &app_config->udp_cfg, &transport_id);
  if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
    goto error;

  /* Add RTP transports */
 // status = pjsua_media_transports_create(&app_config->rtp_cfg);
 // if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
  //  goto error;

#if LOCAL_ACCOUNT
  {
    if (status == PJ_SUCCESS  && transport_id != -1)
    {
      /* Add local account */
      pjsua_acc_add_local(transport_id, PJ_TRUE, &aid);
    }
  }
#endif

  /* */
  sip_manage_codec();

  /* Initialization is done, now start pjsua */
  status = pjsua_start();
  if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
    goto error;

  return status;
error:
  sip_cleanup(app_config);
  return status;
}
```

Comment: Is this code is to handle connection when network changes occur in SIP? Because right now I have to crreate new connection every time whenever network changes occue in SIP in ios.